# visible, display doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, display

i have a div and a link. so when i click the link it should Show me the div. but the Problem now is, i see the div only for a second and then the div hide again.

Why?

```
...
<div id = 'zuordnen'>
    test
</div>
```

...

```
echo "<a href = '' ><img src = './images/zuordnen_menu.png' border=0 style =' width:1vw; height: 2vh;' onClick = 'showzuordnen();'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function showzuordnen()
{
    document.getElementById("zuordnen").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

CSS:

```
#zuordnen {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 6vh;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    left: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because clicking the link reloads the page since you're not doing anything to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *j0869* pointed out the problem is the page is refreshed every time you click the image because the image is within an **anchor** tag.
To solve this just **remove** the anchor tag (`<a>`) that wraps your image.

Have a look at the code pen to see it working: http://codepen.io/HywelMartin/pen/BjBxaj

If you really need the anchor tag just change the `href=''` to `href='#'`.